# How to pass lambda expressions as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am beginner at using lambda expressions.

I have a list of dealers, foreach dealer I have to calculate grade.

The request is that the grade calculation to be separated into a separate method.

So I am writing the below two methods, however I am unable to pass parameters to `CalculateGrade()` method,

```
public IEnumerable<Dealers> GetDealerGrades(IEnumerable<Dealers> gradeData)
{
    return gradeData
        .GroupBy(row => new { row.Name })
        .Select(g => new Dealers
        {
            Name = g.Key.Name,
            TotalPoints = CalculateGrade(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints),
                                         y => y.MaxPoints,
                                         z => Convert.ToDouble(z.Weightage)) 
        })
        .ToList();
}

private double CalculateGrade(double d1, int d2, double d3)
{
    return ( d1 / d2 ) 
        * d3 == 0.00 ? 1
        : d3;
}
```

Can somebody advise how to pass parameters in this , or how to pass lamda expressions and calculate grade?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: This: `.GroupBy(row => new { row.Name })` can be written as `.GroupBy(row => row.Name)`, no `new` necessary.

Comment: if I remove new, I am getting exception - Error 31 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement C:\Users\DEV7\Documents\csdev\trunk\DWIZA\App_Code\Support\AngieStats.cs 497 35 C:\...\DWIZA\

Comment: If you make the replace, you have to change the `g.Key.Name` to `g.Key`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need that:

```
return gradeData
    .GroupBy(row => row.Name)
    .Select(g => new Dealers
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        TotalPoints = g.Sum(x => CalculateGrade(Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints),
                                                x.MaxPoints,
                                                Convert.ToDouble(x.Weightage)))
    })
    .ToList();
```

It will call `CalculateGrade` method on every element from group and sum returned values into `TotalPoints` property.

Or you can change your `CalculateGrade` to take `IEnumerabale<Dealers>`:

```
private double CalculateGrade(IEnumerable<Dealers> dealers)
{
    // calculations here
    return dealers.Sum(x => CalculateGrade(Convert.ToDouble(x.RecievedPoints),
                                            x.MaxPoints,
                                            Convert.ToDouble(x.Weightage)))
}
```

And use it in your query:

```
return gradeData
    .GroupBy(row => row.Name)
    .Select(g => new Dealers
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        TotalPoints = CalculateGrade(g)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: how can I handle calculation in CalculateGrade() if I pass enumerable dealers?

Comment: You can use LINQ as well.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't solve your problem, but it gives you an overview how to send lambdas into methods

You would use Func & Action to pass lambdas into a method

**Func**

Can have 1 - 15 input parameters and must have an output parameter

**Action**

Can have 1 - 16 input parameters with no output parameter

ie, how I imagine they do it in EntityFramework for a where predicate

```
public static List<People> Filter<TEntity>(this List<People> myList, Func<TEntity, TResult> predicate)
{
    return myList.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

the usage would then be something like

```
myList.Filter(ml => ml.Age > 18);
```